# Intermittent BSOD after installing SSD on Sony Vaio

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, ssd, bsod, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio flip 15" hybrid laptop, model SVF15N12SN for about 3 months. A couple of days ago, I replaced the hard-disk with the a Samsung 840 EVO 500GB SSD (model MZ-7TE500BW).

This was a fresh install of Window 8.1. I down loaded most drivers from the Sony support site and there are no "unknown" devices in the Device Manager.

Once is a while (about 3-4 times in a day), the system hangs completely (including mouse) and a few minutes later, there is a BSOD.

The BSOD indicates a DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE error. Analysis of the minidump on osronline.com reveals the following:

```
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time (usually 10 minutes).
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe0007aae42e0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff800a1cbf930, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0007e93e8b0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  53d0f1d4

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff8005201f000 pci

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`a1cbf8f8 fffff800`a0479586 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe000`7aae42e0 fffff800`a1cbf930 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`a1cbf900 fffff800`a04794a6 : ffffe000`7e2292c0 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 fffff800`a02c3190 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
fffff800`a1cbf960 fffff800`a02bf760 : 00000000`00000000 fffff800`a1cbfab0 ffffe000`7e2292f8 ffffe000`7c2d0f45 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
fffff800`a1cbf9b0 fffff800`a03d47ea : fffff800`a0563180 fffff800`a0563180 fffff800`a05caa00 ffffe000`7d7d2880 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x4f0
fffff800`a1cbfc60 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`a1cc0000 fffff800`a1cba000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_nvlddmkm_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_nvlddmkm_IMAGE_pci.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

I've updated all my drivers, scanned the SSD for errors - but the problem won't go away. Please help.

Comment: nvlddmkm = nVIDIA driver. Have you tried a newer driver directly from nVIDIA? http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77841/en-us

Comment: Yes, I did download a latest driver about a couple of hours ago. Since then, there has been no crash. Will wait and see if this has solved the problem.

Comment: ok, report back in 1 or 2 days if the issue is fixed or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing the latest nVidia Drivers from their web-site. No further crashes have happened since updating the drivers.

[nVidia Driver Download Page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)